# Need to lighten a color within the variables passed in a LESS mixin

Tags: less

I am currently updating the bootstrap source less files for a project and I have to modify the hover state for the buttons.  The end goal is something along these lines:

```
.btn-primary {
  .buttonBackground(@btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight, @btnPrimaryBackground);

  &.hover {
    .buttonBackground( lighten(@btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight, %20), lighten(@btnPrimaryBackground, %20));
  }
}
```

However, that returns a compile error.  Any thoughts on this issue?  I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm at a loss.  Thanks in advance.

P.S. - I will also be using the :hover pseudo-class, but for sake of example I'm using a simple class.

Comment: For future questions it might be a good idea to include the actual compiler error. In this case `Syntax error: expected ')' got '%'` says a lot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the percent sign after the number (`20%` instead of `%20`)

Comment: Thanks @freejosh.  You know those days when you've been up too long and look at something too much...   Cheers!